# QProgressBar hanging at 98%

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a beginner in Qt and I'm trying to show process bar for my application’s gui . i have written following code

```
void my_app::progress()
{
  int val=1;
  while(process.state()!=0)
  {
    ui->progressBar->setValue(val++);
  }
  ui->progressBar->setValue(100);
}
```

but progress bar is hanging at 98% . Can any one suggest me some solution .
thank you !

Comment: Would help if we could see what goes on in process.state(), I suppose...

Comment: Looks good. The problem should be inside process.state().

Answer (score 2):

Two possible points: QProcess:::state() does not enter the Qt event loop - so calling it repeatedly will not update your application; all your Qt logic hangs. And verify the progressBar initialization: If the progressBar property "maximum" is not exactly 100 it'll will not reach 100%. Your "val" also ignores the "progressBar" maximum, so it needs a fix:

```
 if( val < ui->progressBar->maximum() )
   ui->progressBar->setValue(val++);
```

Most jobs have a clear concept of progress, which is not obvious here. Your while loop could be too fast to visually recognize the progress steps. Consider substituting the while loop with a signal/slot pair to sync the progressBar. This will also allow Qt to enter the event loop at times to update your app. Consider using the signal QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput() if your called process outputs something reasonable to stdout. Maybe your process does something, ie fills a buffer, whose size you can use to indicate progress - or simply outputs a count to stdout. Let me sketch here:

```
.. Somewhere in your my_app constructor ...
.. ui->progressBar->setRange(0, 100); ..
.. connect( this, SIGNAL(processProgressSignal(int)), this, SLOT(progressSlot(int) ); ..
.. connect( &process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(processProgress()) ); ..

Q_SIGNALS:
void processProgressSignal( int val );


Q_SLOTS:
void my_app::processProgress()
{
     int val = 1;

     // Insert your process progress calculation here
     // Example: Parse the result of QByteArray QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()
     // Example: val = ( buffer.currLength / buffer.maxLength ) * 100;

     Q_EMIT processProgressSignal( val );
}

void my_app::progressSlot(int val)
{
     if( val < ui->progressBar->maximum() )
       ui->progressBar->setValue(val++);     
}
```

If that does not help, make sure that process.state() is 100 times "true" - to allow 100 iterations of your loop. qDebug() is your friend !

Good Luck!