# Display QProcess output in another window

Tags: c++, qt, pipe, signals-slots, qprocess

I'm using the QT Creator on Ubuntu.
I have GUI with a mainwindow and another window called "progress".
Upon clicking a button the QProcess starts and executes an rsync command which copies a folder into a  specific directory. I created a textbrowser which reads the output from the rsync command. Also clicking the button causes the "progress" window to pop up.
So far so so good, now my problem.
Instead of showing the rsync output in my mainwindow i want it to be in progress.
I've tried several methods to get the QProcess into the progress via connect but that doesn't seem to work.

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

         if (ui->checkBox->isChecked()
           )
       m_time ="-t";


    QObject parent;
    m_myProcess =  new QProcess();
    connect(m_myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this, SLOT(printOutput()));

           QString program = "/usr/bin/rsync";

           arguments << "-r" << m_time << "-v" <<"--progress" <<"-s"

               << m_dir
               << m_dir2;




           m_myProcess->start(program, arguments);

          }
```

progress.cpp

```
void Progress::printOutput()
{


  ui->textBrowser->setPlainText(m_myProcess->readAllStandardOutput());
}
```

I know it's pretty messy iv'e tried alot of things and haven't cleaned the code yet also I'm pretty new to c++.
My goal was to send the QProcess (m_myProcess) to progress via connect but that didn't seem to work.
Can you send commands like `readyReadAllStandardOutput` via connect to other windows (I don't know the right term )?
Am I doing a mistake or is there just another way to get the output to my progress window ?

Comment: post a minimal example please. this is almost unreadable. [Check out this answer to a related question for QProcess->progressbar mechanisms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166939/qprogressbar-hanging-at-98/10169668#10169668)

Comment: Okay it should be readable now. Hopefully...
Also thats's not my problem, but still usefull for the future thanks.

Comment: what is happening? nothing is being displayed?

Comment: No , when i try to run it i get a error that m_myProcess was not declared in the progress.cpp scope.
"m_myProcess' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: this is a compilation error *facepalm*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m_myProcess` is a member of the class `MainWindow` and you haven't made it visible to the class `Progress`. That's why you have the ***compilation error***

> m_myProcess was not declared in this scope

What you could do:

1. [Redirect standard error of m_myProcess to standard output](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessChannelMode-enum), such that you also print what is sent to standard error (unless you want to do something else with it). Using

   ```
   m_myProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
   ```
2. Make the process object available outside `MainWindow`

   ```
   QProcess* MainWindow::getProcess()
   {
      return  m_myProcess;
   }
   ```
3. Read the process output line by line in `Progress`. It needs to be saved in a buffer because `readAllStandardOutput()` only return the data which has been written since the last read.

   ```
   ... // somewhere
   connect(window->getProcess(), SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(printOutput())
   ...

   void Progress::printOutput(){
      //bigbuffer is member
      bigbuffer.append(myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();)
      ui->textBrowser->setPlainText(bigbuffer);
   }
   ```

Comment: Uhhm where do i put 
QProcess* MainWindow::getProcess() { return m_myProcess;}

Comment: In MainWindow. Are you beginning with c++?

Comment: Dang it didn't changed when i edited my comment.
I put in mainwindow.h public:
And got the error:  error: extra qualification 'MainWindow::' on member 'getProcess'

Comment: You have issues with c++ syntax, and I am sorry but I will not fix every compilation error you encounter. search them directly on SO or on google. good luck.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for bringing me on the right path.

Comment: After trying a little bit and experimenting a lot it worked thanks to your code.